# sql limit commend does not work properly

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem in sql select so the table is something like this :

```
id   uid  content         date        type
2    1    lorem ipusem#1  1391817600  1
3    1    lorem ipusem#2  1391899005  1
...
```

what i want to do ,is to select the first 5 (in this case 2) which is int the future and order them by the date (to pick the first closest five massages to now)
so here is my sql query

```
('SELECT `content` FROM `mvc` WHERE type = 1 and `date` > '.$date.' ORDER BY `date` ASC limit 5')
```

(i copied the line from the code )
for some reason the query only select the first one even though they both fits to the query (when i use Desc the other one is selected)

```
<?php
class getAnnounc {
    private $db;
    private $raw;
    public function getAnnounc($database){
        $this-> db = $database;
        $this->getRaw();
    }
    private function getRaw(){
        $date = time();
        $this->raw = $this->db->query('SELECT `content` FROM `mvc` WHERE type = 1 and `date` > '.$date.' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 5')or die(mysqli_error());
        $this->raw = $this->raw->fetch_assoc();
        echo var_dump($this->raw);
    }
}
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','ortMallot') or mysqli_error();
$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
new getAnnounc($db);
```

Comment: @JonasT . . . `limit 5` is perfectly fine syntax for this problem.

Comment: no this is not changing anything ...

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the code processing the results.  If two rows pass the `where` clause filter, then both should be picked up regardless of the `order by`.

Comment: i thought this problem is in the limit ..

Comment: any way i ran the same query throw php my admin interface and got the same result

Comment: I guess, it's problem in code processing in php, first try sql in mysql then please try to add "id" in select , you will get 5 rows.'SELECT `id`,`content`.....'

Comment: Are you sure that is the entire query?  Why is it in parentheses?  And what is the format of `$date`?

Comment: the brackets are from the function (it doesn't really matter). the date is in unix timestemp

Comment: Your code doesn't have a loop for fetching multiple results.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: i just used var_dump to see the object that mysqli returns ..

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you want descending order, not ascending:

```
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 5
```

It doesn't explain why you're getting only one of the two, but I suspect that might an issue with your PHP variable's relationship with the WHERE condition.

Comment: Can you post the code that sets $date? It would be helpful to know what that evaluates to - I don't think it's a problem with your SQL syntax. Also, what DB engine are you using? Some DBMS use the keywork TOP in place of LIMIT, e.g. Teradata

Comment: @MattDexter He tagged his post under mysql,

Comment: What's the data type of the date field? It's not a date convention I'm familiar with. If you're saying lorem ipsum#1 is the missing one, then 1391817600 is less than the number for lorem ipsum#2. Is it possible that that date evaluates to the past & not the future?

Comment: Nevermind, I see - that is a Unix timestamp. Both do evaluate to the future.